# How do I receive a custom webhook in an IIS hosted website?

Tags: c#, iis, webhooks

Here is what I have done:

1 - I have installed the nuget package: Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Custom 1.2.0-beta

2 - I configured the `WebApiConfig` to receive custom webhooks:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.InitializeReceiveCustomWebHooks(); //<<<---
    }
```

3 - I set up a secret key in the web.config:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    ...
    <add key="MS_WebHookReceiverSecret_GenericJson" value="z=SECRET"/> 
  </appSettings>
```

4 - I have written a basic receiver (with the genericjson hook capture)

```
public class GenericJsonWebHookHandler : WebHookHandler
{
    public static string dataReceived;
    public GenericJsonWebHookHandler()
    {
        this.Receiver = "genericjson";
    }

    public override Task ExecuteAsync(string generator, WebHookHandlerContext context)
    {
        // Get JSON from WebHook
        JObject data = context.GetDataOrDefault<JObject>();

        if (context.Id == "i")
        {
            // do stuff
        }
        else if (context.Id == "z")
        {
            // do more stuff
            dataReceived = data.ToString();

            File.Create(@"c:\test\test1.txt");
        }

        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

Now, one would expect with the steps above, if a webhook sender is set up to publish Json to the IIS hosted site, it should capture the notification as Json, assign the captured data to `dataReceived` and write a blank text file to `c:\test\test.txt` - **which was not the case**

Currently, I am testing this using Team Foundation Server to send a webhook test to `https://mywebbhooksite.com:5050/?z=SECRET`, and It **succeeds** - however, when I check if that little test file has been created, it's not there. I also have some javascript running on the homepage to poll for any changes to `dataReceived` but I see nothing is happening.

**Mentioning here: I have a remote debugger attached to the w3wp.exe process, the breakpoint on ExecuteAsync and GenericJsonWebHookHandler does not get hit**

Are there any other specific setup that needs to be done in order for the webhook to be captured?

Comment: Are you sure that your `context.Id` contained a z?  I see its a parameter name, but it is not clear to me in this example exactly what the contents of `context` is.  I would verify you are going through your `if/else` if statements correctly.

Comment: Also - are you sure your app has write access to that specific location?

Comment: What @Tommy said. You need to do more debugging. Use a logger or test your handler locally. You can't just dump it on the server and expect us to mentally debug it. If you do want to debug it on the server, remove all irrelevant code from `ExecuteAsync` and simply dump a `File.Create()` statement in there, nothing more. 99% chance the IIS user account has no permissions to write in `C:\test`.

Comment: @Tommy I am positive - gave permissions

I cannot see why the `context.Id` won't contain z, as I did the same webhook, except from Zapier (where my site was hosted on Azure instead. The guys here didn't like the idea of hosting a basic site like this on azure)

Comment: @CodeCaster That's why I also wrote a heartbeat in Javascript to read if `dataReceived` gets populated - just incase the file doesn't write for xyz reason

Comment: Again, go debug. I don't know what your JavaScript looks like or whether it hits the same handler, as you don't show it, so we can't say anything about it. If you must test this on the server, consider attaching a debugger.

Comment: Trust me when I say - the remote debugger is attached to w3wp.exe. I should rather have mentioned that the method doesn't even get hit - and that's what I need to know - did I miss any possible setup required for webhooks to be received by an IIS site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took a filthy approach which works

I ditched `GenericJsonWebHookHandler` and instead I have utilized the `Application_BeginRequest()` event in `WebApiApplication` instead to intercept data posted by the sender Webhook. The body of the hook resides in the `HttpRequest.Request.Inputstream`, which can be opened using a streamreader. The contents can be read onto a `string` and parsed into a JObject (if the body of the request sent by the webhook Request is JSon)

Here is my code.

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        if (!Request.HttpMethod.Equals("post", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) {
            return; 
        }

        string documentContents;
        using (var receiveStream = Request.InputStream)
        {
            using (var readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                documentContents = readStream.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        try
        {
            var json = JObject.Parse(documentContents);
            File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\test\keys.txt", new[] { documentContents, "\r\n", json.ToString() });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
             // do something
        }
    }
```

The test:

I went onto my webhook and commenced a webhook test. It published the request with the json. HTTP 200 was the response from the server.

Breakpoint was hit. The `HttpMethod` picked up the post. The Request's `InputStream` was read and stored in `documentContents`. `JObject.Parse` fired off and put the contents of the post into a `JObject` variable called `json`

The contents of `json` was written to a file stored on the server - indicating that the request was properly received.

**What I plan to do to improve this, for security**

For security purposes, I will encrypt the secret key I set in the web.config, and set the encrypted key in the web.config instead, and after that match it with the incoming URL Query parameters (using the same encryption algorithm) to see if that key is present and exactly the same